# Merge two opaque images to get a transparent one

Tags: java, pdf, imagemagick, jai

I need to extract an image from a PDF.

But since its background is transparent it's saved with a soft mask to create transparency.

While I'm able to extract the two opaque images below, I have no idea if there's a way to recreate the original image in Java. Could I use JAI?

Below there's the "main" image:

[image: img.jpg]

and here there's the corresponding soft mask:

[image: mask.jpg]

I tried with ImageMagick with the command:

```
convert mask.jpg -background Black -alpha shape copy.png
```

and I almost got what I need but the foreground color is only black while the original one has also blue as foreground color.

Comment: Maybe show us how it is supposed to look when it is finished.

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably want something like this, but it is hard to tell as you do not show us your expected result:

```
convert -fuzz 20% main.jpg -transparent black   \
     mask.jpg -compose copy-opacity -composite  \
     result.png
```

[image]

The `-fuzz` allows *nearly* black pixels in `main.jpg` to become transparent. The mask image is then loaded and its opacity copied to the main image.

Comment: Wonderful! It's exactly what I need, but is there a Java equivalent?

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak Java - I assumed you were happy with the command-line interface too, since you showed what you had been trying there. Maybe you could `shell exec` the ImageMagick command I gave, or have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296075/how-would-i-use-the-imagemagick-library-with-processing